# when build GBM and DRF in H2O, is score_each_iteration the same as score_tree_interval = 1?

Tags: h2o

I am using H2O to build GBM and DRF model now, I found both score_each_iteration the same as score_tree_interval are described to make the early stop repeatable. But is score_each_iteration the same as score_tree_interval = 1? If yes, why we need score_each_iteration, we can just use score_tree_interval = 1 instead

Answer (score 2):

The [`score_each_iteration`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/score_each_iteration.html) parameter turns on/off scoring at each iteration -- and the [`score_tree_interval`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/score_tree_interval.html) parameter defines what that interval is.  For example, if `score_tree_interval = 5`, then an interval is a period of five trees (not one).  So it would score every 5 trees.

The default scoring is not based on fixed intervals -- it scores more often at the beginning and less often towards the end.  That's the reason we have these parameters to override this behavior.

Comment: If I only use score_each_iteration = True without score_tree_interval. Does that mean score_tree_interval = 1?

Comment: @Gavin No because the default for `score_tree_interval` is 0 which means a fixed interval is not used (we use a dynamic interval instead).

Comment: Erin, so what does each "iteration" mean in the H2O document of "score_each_iteration". Based on your explanation it is clearly not stands for each tree.